# onkeyup or onkeypress javascript event issue - password status updates

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-events

**Programming Question First** (from w3 schools)

The programming example way below (from W3 schools) is nice and easy, it works on their website but I'm really confused on something.

```
onkeypress="return noNumbers(event)"
```

why is there a return before the function?  What does it do?   If you know the answer to that - how did you find out that information?  My guess would be, that it allows the keypressed function to continue processing the keystroke since my event "interupted" it?

***also*** - I have been trying to see what 'event' is.  It doesnt seem to be a keyword.  I spent > hour trying to find what it is.  It doesnt seem to be assigned anywhere in their code example.  Normally in that spot you would see 'this'.  If it's a not assigned variable will it always pass the event handler?  Confused...

**What I want to do with their function**

I want to make a password strength checker AS you type.  I was looking at their example so I could figure out how to capture keys (cross browser and minimal IE7).  My idea was...

```
<input type="password" name="pword" maxlength="50" size="50" id="field_pword" onkeyup="PasswordStrength(name, 8, 'relaxed')" onblur="CheckField(name, 8, 1)">
```

***note:*** Yes, I know it's better to assign event handlers outside of the html but I couldn't see a way to pass variables to it unless it was inline.  I'm a novice so I may have overlooked something but... thats why I do it IN the HTML.

***also***, IS IT BAD how I am passing name?  it does send pword to the function but am I doing something wrong there?  Should I just make it a constant string?   It works as is, but sometimes just because something works... doesn't mean it's correct.  :)

```
onkeyup="PasswordStrength('pword', 8, 'relaxed')" onblur="CheckField('pword', 8, 1)">
```

My checkfield function works (I use it after every field) I recently added in PasswordStrength.  My question is...  my new function isn't passing the event hander so how can I check what key is pressed?  Can I do this?

```
onkeyup="PasswordStrength(name, 8, 'relaxed', event)"
```

or should it read...

```
onkeyup="return PasswordStrength(name, 8, 'relaxed', event)"
```

If I can't pass whatever 'event' is that way, inside my function can I accurately get what the key pressed was without a big mess of code?  Since I'm learning I need examples to be as simple as possible (please).

Using my function I was going to do it this way but I still don't know how to get what key was pressed...

```
function PasswordStrength(sField, iMinLength, sStrength, e?)
{
var form = document.forms[0];
var gc = form[sField].value;
    // once I have the value I can do checking but it would be nice to have WHAT key
    // was pressed
    // the e? above is where I was thinking of passing the event
```

***W3 example I was pulling some knowledge from...***

```
function noNumbers(e)
{
var keynum;
var keychar;
var numcheck;

if(window.event) // IE
{
keynum = e.keyCode;
}
else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
{
keynum = e.which;
}
keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
numcheck = /\d/;
return !numcheck.test(keychar);
}
</script>

<form>
Type some text (numbers not allowed):
<input type="text" onkeypress="return noNumbers(event)" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

As someone is typing I was going to change the text using innerHTML beside the password field to say, "Weak", "Ok", "Good", "Perfect" or something along those lines for the password status.  I'd love to do it how google does it with a graphic to the left of the field but I don't know how to do that simply.  lol.

Is my way fixable?  Do you have a better way to do this that I don't know about?  Much appreciated.  Awaiting an infusion of wisdom...

Comment: Can you possibly summarize your question and maybe even break it up into a couple of questions?  I would like to help you but this is too much to digest.  I am guessing that others would agree.  No offense ;).

Comment: Hey there - I removed the jquery poll question from above to make it a lot smaller.  I can ask about jquery another day.  I"m just trying to make a password strength checker that checks the strength of the password as you type.  The code @ the bottom is what I was looking at from w3 schools but I didn't understand how they did some things (thus my ponderings at the top).  In the middle, is what I was attemping but I don't see how I can use pieces of their code with mine how I did my try.  The bottom is the w3 example I was checking out.   I tried breaking it down as best as I could...

Comment: OK--After a quick Google search, I am going to start here: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/

Comment: You may want to do the same concurrently.

Comment: Hi PerryCS, I won't post this as an answer, because it isn't a magic pill or anything, but after reviewing about a dozen plugins, I think that this will be best for your needs:  http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/password_strength.  Hope it helps!

Comment: wow, that password meter makes me drool...  I didnt event think of looking specifically for a premade password function.  I'll see what people post to my making my own and see if I can do it.  But, I appreciate the links.  I'll check them out for sure.

Comment: Great!  Good luck Perry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The "return" word makes it so that if the function returns `false`, that gets passed back to the event and stops the keystroke from being processed by the browser (and appearing in the input field if that's what the event is on).

2) `event` is the Event object, which contains information on the event such as what key wa pressed, where the event was fired, etc.

3) Yes, it is bad  how you are passing `name`, because you aren't passing it. Use `this.name` instead.

4) In this case, you don't need `return` because you aren't trying to stop a keystroke from being added to the textbox. Similarly, you don't need to pass `event` because you can pass `this.value` to get the contents of the textbox.

5) You can just pass `this` instead of `this.name`, `this.value` or whatever other values.Then, in the function, get the properties from the single argument.

6) Once you pass the entire value with `this.value`, you can run your tests on that. There is absolutely no need to know what key was pressed, especially as things like `Ctrl+V` would completely screw you over.

7) You can have a `<div>` and change its width and/or background colour to make a sort of strength bar indicator.

Comment: I was looking over my old questions and realized how little I knew of the structure of JS vs now.  I want to thank you for answers like this which helped my early development.  I had no idea what event was or where it came from.  Coming from a 6502 assembly background and jumping into JS was pretty hard... but, thanks to many quality answers from yourself and others my knowledge has skyrocketed and I am doing some very complex things now... so, just stopped in to say THANKS for taking the time to answer my question in a clear way!  Building blocks on which more knowledge is piled :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to your first programming questions:

- Your suggestion is right, to return a value inside of an event
  lets you interrupt the action depending on the values content. Returning `false` inside `onclick`
  will end in the click not to be done. So `<a href="http://test.de"
  onclick="return false;">linkname</a>` wont link you to anything if
  JavaScript is active.
- `event` is simply a variable declared before it runs into the actual event, further explanation below.

You know the elements eventhandler attributes in JavaScript?
They are functions i.e.

```js
document.createElement('div').onclick = function( event ){
  //do something...
  return true || false;
};
```

if you assign an `onclick` attribute to a tag it's simply another adjusted way to create this anonymous function. So

```html
<input onclick="this.value = 'can\'t click me :P Mouse X: ' + event.clientX; return false;" type="text" id="ip" />
```

will behave as if you created an anonymous function taking the argument `event`.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('ip').onclick = function( event ){
    this.value = 'can\'t click me :P Mouse X: ' + event.clientX; return false;
  };
};
```

This will behave exactly equal except of the delayed assignment.

The `this` keyword is always the owner object whose property function you're accessing or the object you're passing to an `apply`/`call` method. In this case it's obviously the owner - the DOM element. So `this.value` is the `input`s value.

The `event` passed to the function is just an object containing some useful information about the current browsers state and miscellaneous. It's having slightly different properties filled with different values in different browsers but the main functionality is the same everywhere.

- As explained above it makes no difference whether you write what you did or this:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var yourElement = document.getElementsByTagName('pword')[0];
  yourElement.onkeyup = function( event ){
    PasswordStrength(this.name, 8, 'relaxed')
  };
};
```

- No it's not really *bad* to use just `name`.. whenever you access a property of the owners object you can omit the `this` keyword. Thus it's simply the same conflict as the one about writing

```html
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
 onload = function(){ alert('hello!') };
//]]></script>
```

instead of `window.onload` or `this.onload` or even `this.window.onload` (which are all theoretically working since the everything containing object has a property named `window` which refers to itself). You could say it's a matter of convention. But since the convention to always access own properties over the `this` keyword (except for `window` which you should access over its property `window`) is strongly established and supported, you probably should write `this.name`.

- That depends on whether you want to eventually interrupt the event and don't let the user finish his `keyup`. Explained above.
- Why shouldn't you be able to pass the `event` object? Just treat it like a normal variable.
- Combining the information above and the example in your question you should be able to get knowledge about which key was pressed.

Comment: Thank you for explaining event more.  I am a sponge taking in all this info... it's just frustrating sometimes not being able to find clear concise information when googling on what everything does.  I'm used to 6502 assembly language and books that told me - if you call this function with this and that it returns this and leaves the cpu state and function exactly like "this" and "that".  Web development seems like a lot of guesswork and it's annoying something works when it shouldn't.  lol.  Needs to be more strict.  I appreciate your comments.

Comment: Someone else answered 1 day before you - can't give both of you credit and the 1st person did answer pretty much everything.  I appreciate your time - I have more knowledge now :)

Comment: @PerryCS No problem, I'm glad if I can help! My only point: "1 day before" is a bit overstated - it was 35 mins (around midnight) ;)

Comment: Ah.... didnt notice the exact time!  lol.  I just saw 2 dates :)    Well, it's last year now but not exactly a year ago :)